# GraphQL AppSync DynamoDB only update one field in mutation

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

So I am working on an app with AWS amplify. I am using a single table design and I am trying to run a mutation where I only update the profile field of the UserV0 in the single table design. I am trying to only update the profile(s3key) but when I run my mutations it deletes the rest of the contents of UserV0.

**Graph QL Schema**

```
type SingleTable @model {
  pk: String! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["sk"])
  sk: String!
  user: UserV0
  post: PostV0
}

type UserV0 {
  name: String
  username: String
  email: String
  profile: String

}

type PostV0 {
  ...
}
```

```
query getUserInfo {
  getSingleTable(pk: "TEST", sk: "TEST") {
    user {
      username
      name
      profile
      email
    }
  }
}

mutation createTable {
  createSingleTable(input: {pk: "TEST", sk: "TEST", user: {email: "email@email.com", name: "testname", profile: "testPath", username: "testusername"}}) {
    updatedAt
  }
}

mutation updateTable {
  updateSingleTable(input: {pk: "TEST", sk: "TEST", user: {profile: "TESTING", username: "TESTING123"}}) {
    createdAt
  }
}
```

If I run the update mutation above, then the entire user is reset and when I check it in my DynamoDB field the name and email fields are all lost. How can I make it so that when I run the mutation, I only update the profile field and leave the other fields without deleting them. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I put in all of the queries and mutations that I am running in AppSync. I run createTable and then getUserInfo and it returns this as it should.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getSingleTable": {
      "user": {
        "username": "testusername",
        "name": "testname",
        "profile": "testPath",
        "email": "email@email.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But after I run the updateTable and then getUserInfo it returns this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getSingleTable": {
      "user": {
        "username": "TESTING123",
        "name": null,
        "profile": "TESTING",
        "email": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the name and email fields are reset, set to null and removed from the DynamoDB database. I am pretty sure it is because it sees the user object as a new input. But how do I get it just recognize that I only want to update certain fields in userV0 and not the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your function `updateSingleTable` uses the UpdateItem operation:

`"operation" : "UpdateItem"`

If you're using `PutItem` which I assume you are, it performs and overwrite and thus removing existing data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html

Under the hood I believe the DynamoDB client is DynamoDB Mapper. As a result, it will delete values if set to null. To avoid this, you must ensure you do not set values to null, instead omit any values not being used in the request.

Comment: I just checked and the resolver is set to update item. Not PutItem

Comment: If you specify values but they are null, then the API will remove them. Do not specify values which are not part of the update.

Comment: I wasn't specifying any other the other values. I am thinking it has to do with the nesting object and the entire user object is getting overwritten. I made some edits to show exactly what I was running.